# I need to convert object into array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I need to convert my object into array of object
My object is below:

```
superman = {
    name: 'Superman',
    'real name': 'Clark Kent',
    height: 75,
    weight: 235,
    hero: true,
    villain: false,
    allies: {superHero: 'Batman',
             superPower: 'He is rich',
             sidekick: 'robin'}
    }
```

& I need it convert into:

```
[
    {name: 'Superman'},
    {realName: 'Clark Kent'},
    {height: 75},
    {weight: 235},
    {hero: true},
    {villain: false},
    {allies: [superHero: 'Batman',
             superPower: 'He is rich',
             sidekick: 'robin']}
]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: You need to convert it into a syntax error?

Comment: in child `allies`, the array cannot set the key.

Comment: The **allies** in your second object is not valid. You show you want an **Array** (square brackets) but use an object notation inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY THIS

```js
var superman = {
    name: 'Superman',
    'real name': 'Clark Kent',
    height: 75,
    weight: 235,
    hero: true,
    villain: false,
    allies: {superHero: 'Batman',
             superPower: 'He is rich',
             sidekick: 'robin'}
    };
var ret = Object.keys(superman).map(function(key) {
  return { [key]: superman[key] };
});
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify every object in your main object to the structure you described (recursively), then use this:

```js
var superman = {
  name: 'Superman',
  'real name': 'Clark Kent',
  height: 75,
  weight: 235,
  hero: true,
  villain: false,
  allies: {
    superHero: 'Batman',
    superPower: 'He is rich',
    sidekick: 'robin'
  }
};

const toArray = (obj) => {
  return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
    const ret = {}
    if (typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(value).length) {
      ret[key] = toArray(value)
    } else {
      ret[key] = value
    }

    return ret
  })
}

console.log(toArray(superman))
```